# Why adding a Foreign Key without drawing the Relationship in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys, relationship

I'm having with building databases, I'm wondering why some people create ( for example in Mysqlworkbench ) two tables (Articles, Categories), with the FK `category_id` in the Article Table, but without actually designing any relationship between the tables. what's the difference between doing it this way and drawing the relation between the tables ?
If both ways are possible, what is the best way of doing it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean: "Designing no relationship"? If you set up a foreign key, you *have* designed a relationship between the two tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Telling the database explicitly what the relationships are can help the database management system. For example, if you require that Articles cannot exist without a Category, the DBMS can be set up to delete all Articles if its Category is destroyed. The biggest help is that when you make a change to a parent, you can have it automatically cascade down to its children. It all comes down to your personal approach to the configuration of your database, as everything foreign keys do when explicitly noted to the DBMS can be done manually with coding yourself.

Source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html and just finished a database management class